# Selenium with nodejs- a process not stop even if the error comes, the issue facing on 107.XX version of chrome browser and chrome driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working in NODE JS (javascript) with selenium webdriver.
Package.json-
`“chai”: “^4.3.6”, “chromedriver”: “^107.0.3”, “geckodriver”: “^3.2.0”, “mocha”: “^10.0.0”, “mochawesome”: “^7.1.3”, “moment”: “^2.29.4”, “selenium-webdriver”: “^4.5.0”, “selenium-standalone”: “^8.2.3"`

file1.js
`it("Test code", async function(){ console.log("START"); await driver.sleep(3000); console.log("HELLO); await driver.findElement(Xpath).sendKeys("TEXT"); console.log("STOP"); })`

the problem has been coming when updating the chrome driver or chrome browser, the issue is when the old code runs and when it doesn't. So is there any problem with this latest version or what?.
EX. I want to run my code like by like TOP to Bottom, which means first run the first line then after next so on, so I am put await `driver.sleep(3000)`, which means the process hold at least 3 sec then after running next step, here before update the version it's working as expected but now some time its work and sometimes not, also not getting an error if found any error during runtime, currently process shows continues ongoing. Even if we put timeout then also not stop after time reach,
if remove the "await" command then do not run sync mode.

really confused what's going on. not getting errors and the process taking more and more time means not stopping automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It may not fix your problem, but you will need to make sure that you have quotes around the word 'Hello' when you are trying to `console.log` it.

```
console.log("HELLO);
```

Should be:

```
console.log("HELLO");
```